# How to shutdown computer when users are logged on?

Tags: shutdown, logout

I am trying to shut down my Ubuntu laptop, but some other users have left their accounts logged-in. (All users are local.) Normal shutdown is blocked because of this.

I can do a hard  shutdown with the power switch, but is there a way to force shutdown from within Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) or use a TTY (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1.</kbd>) Then you have to login using administrative account or root.

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always use

```
sudo init 0
```

to bring it down as well - a few less characters to type but not as pretty :)